# PayPal Smart Button Payment Not Going Through

Tags: angular, paypal

I have a PayPal Smart Button on my Angular web page that looks like the following:

```
paypal.Buttons({
      createOrder: (data, actions) => {
        return actions.order.create({
          purchase_units: [
            {
              description: this.product.description,
              amount: {
                currency_code: 'USD',
                value: this.product.price,
              }
            },
          ],

          application_context: {
            shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING'
          }
        });
      },

      onApprove: async (data, actions) => {
        this.dataService.reserveReservation();
        const order = actions.order.capture();
        alert('Transaction Completed!');
      }
    }).render(this.paypalElement.nativeElement);
```

95% of the time the purchase goes through, but occasionally `dataService.reserveReservation` gets called without the payment going through. Is there some time of error that `actions.order.capture()` returns if the payment fails, or why is the `onApprove` callback being called when the payment isn't going through and doesn't show up anywhere in my PayPal home activity tab? How can I make sure the payment is going through every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Captures can fail; examples of some failure scenarios are listed at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/funding-failure/ -- hence, your code belongs after the capture's resolution.

Specifically, see the sample at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client -- your code should be in the `.then()` promise chain, after `actions.order.capture()` successfully finalizes the payment.

And make sure you return the result correctly to onApprove's caller.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's a lifesaver. I do have one question, why do we return the result of actions.order.capture()? If so what would I really be returning if I use await/async instead of .then

Comment: I don't know of a correct implementation other than what's in the sample